# Is it possible to implement single-sign-on SSO between C# .Net application and Laravel 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, laravel, single-sign-on

Our company's Client portal if developed with C#. Clients do authenticate on this portal.

Now I developed a new service with a small portal using Laravel 5.7 (let's call this the service portal).

The two portals are on different domains.

I want to integrate the new service portal in the main portal without doing authentication twice.

What I want to accomplish is that when a client authenticates on the original Client portal (C# portal) and clicks a link, he gets redirected to the service portal (laravel app) without being authenticated.

So I don't know if is it possible to accomplish this ? If so, please point me on how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at OAuth - https://oauth.net/

Comment: What kind of authentication mechanism is done on the C# side. Your requirement seems to be in the direction of SSO, which will need much more work

Comment: Yes. I am looking at these two packages:
https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2
https://github.com/legalthings/sso